# How to access nested properties inside params Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm confused with something. I'm trying to access a nested attribute in the params like so:

```
var = params['filter']['status']
```

And I get the following error: `undefined method`[]' for nil:NilClass`
When I do the following:

```
render json: params['filter']
```

I get the following result: `{"status":"complete"}`

How can I access `params['filter']['status']`?

I've tried: `var = params['filter']['status']`, `params[:filter][:status]`

And always get the same error.

When I've done `params['filter'].class` I got `{}`

**EDIT:**

This is the result of `puts params`:

```
Parameters: {"filter"=>"{\"status\":\"complete\"}", "paging.pageNumber"=>"1", "paging.pageSize"=>"10", "sorting"=>"{}", "order"=>{}}
```

Comment: How do your `params` look like?

Comment: what does ```puts params``` give you?

Comment: Can you show the form by which you are posting this data to controller ?

Comment: It looks to me like you need to parse JSON first. Try doing this: ```JSON.parse(params)['filter']['status']```